# Inverse of log2 transform through ggplot + coord_trans

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

I would like to do inverse of log2 transform on my coordinates only.

From what I understand, exp_trans() and log_trans() go together, so

```
gg.plot +
  coord_trans(x="exp")
```

would perform inverse of log on the coordinates.

However, I noticed there is nothing like 2_trans() for log2_trans().

What are my options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use `scales::exp_trans(base = ...)` as a function instead of by name. Demonstrated for the y-axis below. The default break calculations are not that pretty with `coord_trans()`. Note that there are warnings about infinite values, but these are likely the expanded axis limits that go below the `[0, Inf]` domain for log-transforms.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(pressure, aes(temperature, pressure)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_log10() +
  coord_trans(y = scales::exp_trans(10))
#> Warning in trans$inverse(continuous_range_coord): NaNs produced
#> Warning in self$trans$y$inverse(panel_params$y.range): NaNs produced
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>